# Rails 4: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce

I am creating a simple ecommerce application with a shopping cart. However when I try to add a product to the cart I get an error

```
NoMethodError at /carts/1/add/1
undefined method `add_item' for []:Array
```

Here are my controllers

- **application_controller.rb**

  ```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def initialize_cart
      @cart = Cart.build_from_hash session
    end
  end
  ```
- **carts_controller.rb**

  ```
  class CartsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :initialize_cart

    def add
      @cart.add_item params[:id]
      set_product
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Added #{product.name} to cart"
    end

    private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
    end
  end
  ```
- **products_controller.rb**

  ```
  class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_filter :initialize_cart

    def index
      @products = Product.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
      @product = Product.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
      @product = Product.new(product_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @product.save
          format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @product.update(product_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @product.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      def set_product
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      end

      def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :image)
      end
  end
  ```

Here are my models

- **product.rb**

  ```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
     mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

     validates_presence_of :name, :price
     validates_numericality_of :price
  end
  ```

*The following are tableless classes in the model directory*

- **cart.rb**

  ```
  class Cart
    attr_reader :items

    def self.build_from_hash hash
      items = if hash["cart"] then
        hash["cart"]["items"].map do |item_data|
          CartItem.new item_data["product_id"], item_data["quantity"]
        end
      else
        []
      end
    end

    def initialize items = []
      @items = items
    end

    def add_item product_id
      item = @items.find {|item| item.product_id == product_id}
      if item
        item.increment
      else
        @items << CartItems.new(product_id)
      end
    end

    def empty?
      @item.empty?
    end

    def serialize
      items = @items.map do |item| 
      {
        "product_id" => item.product_id,
        "quantity" => item.quantity 
      }
    end

    {
      "cart" => {
      "items" => items
      }
    }
    end
  end
  ```
- **cart_item.rb**

  ```
  class CartItem
    attr_reader :product_id, :quantity

    def initialize product_id, quantity = 1
      @product_id = product_id
      @quantity = quantity
    end

   def increment
      @quantity += 1
   end

   def product
      Product.find product_id
   end
  end
  ```

Here is a screenshot of my error

[image: error_screenshot]

#### Solved the **No Method Error** by making initializing @items array in the Cart class  at the end of the *build_from_hash* method

Here is the solution

```
def self.build_from_hash hash
    items = if hash["cart"] then
      hash["cart"]["items"].map do |item_data|
        CartItem.new item_data["product_id"], item_data["quantity"]
      end
    else
      []
    end

    new items    
  end
```

Now I am getting a new error

```
NameError at /carts/1/add/1
uninitialized constant Cart::CartItems
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `add_item` method for arrays which is what your `@cart` object is when it is returned from `Cart.build_from_hash`. Well, in this case it looks like it's passing through your "else" statement which is returning an empty array. Is that what you intended to occur?

If so, you append to arrays using something like this:

`array << "object"`

Edit here because comment editing sucks:

Alright, you're initializing `@cart` by using:

`@cart = Cart.build_from_hash session`

`Cart.build_from_hash` returns an `Array` object. This is where you need to be returning a `Cart` object if you want to be able to use `Cart.add_item.` The easiest way would just add `return self` to the end of `Cart.build_from_hash` but I'm fairly certain that will open up other problems if you're using `@cart` as an actual array at some point.

Of course if you want this `Cart` object to be saved in your database you'll have to actually create it at some point unless you just wanted to keep all the data in an array until the very end.

Comment: Yes...I want an empty item array at the start so that I can just continue adding products to the array as one shops

Comment: @Mutuma Then as I said, you'll want to use `@cart << params[:id]` rather than `add_item`. Where'd you get that from anyways?

Comment: The add_item is an instance method in the Cart class.

Comment: Ah ok well I see now. Your `@cart` object isn't a `Cart` object at all it's an empty array and arrays aren't defined with an `add_item` method hence your error. You need to get `build_from_hash` to return a `Cart` object if you want `@cart` to have access to `add_item`

Comment: Please provide an example of how I would copy the logic in add_item to the answer you've provided since the methods checks for if the item exists and adds a count to it and if not creates a new item in the cart

Comment: Now I get you, but please check the application_controller, in that way when I build from hash I just obtain a object of Cart that is an array

Comment: When I do @cart.class it returns Array .. how would I make that array an instance of Cart?

Comment: @Mutuma check the edit I just made. Posting long code excerpts in comments sucks

Comment: `CartItems.new` isn't a thing. Your class is called `CartItem` so you need to use `CartItem.new` (it's in your add_item method). Keep track of what's plural and what isn't and your life will be much easier.